# How can the music at 1:20 of Ryoji Ikeda's 's superposition be classified?

Tags: identify-this-genre

1. I'm referring to the music at [1:20](https://vimeo.com/49873167) of Ryoji Ikeda's *superposition*.
2. Are there any modernist composers (preferably acknowledged by musicologists) who have composed this type of music?

User [Your Uncle Bob](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/40114/your-uncle-bob) [commented](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/83090/how-can-the-music-at-120-of-ryoji-ikedas-s-superposition-be-classified#comment138741_83090):

> The use of "tone clusters" and the related concept of "sound mass" can lead to results that are somewhat similar; e.g. some parts of Kraanerg by Xenakis. See these Wikipedia pages for more info and a list of composers and compositions: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_cluster en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_mass